# Performance difference Kerberos versus NTLM

Tags: performance, kerberos, ntlm

I understand that Kerberos has better performance than NTLM.

But does anyone have any figures or any experience of how much better it is?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that Kerberos has a better performance than NTLM? The Kerberos Process of Authentication is much more complicated the the NTLM one. Could you point me to any source?

Comment: NTLM does 3 http requests and needs to contact AD for each web request. Kerberos has a single request to the web server.

Comment: Ah okay so you mean the performance after the authentication process. Then i agree ^^

Comment: These links are very usefull:
http://windowsitpro.com/windows/resolve-performance-problems-associated-authentication-scaling (at the end recommends Kerberos)
http://www.msexchangegeek.com/exchange-2010-intermittent-password-prompts-in-outlook-clients-ntlm-bottleneck/ (at the end recommends kerberos)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kerberos is better when it comes to performance. Mainly because it is a lot less chatty than NTLM. For more details refer to...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee914605.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Kerberos performance *and* security is far better than NTLMv1 or NTLMv2.
It's not even up for debate.

Every third packet needs to be sent to the domain controller for challenge/response when using NTLM. That slows down your domain controllers and causes cascading performance issues for all the other services a DC performs.

NTLMv1 hashes can be cracked in about 8 seconds with an 8088 processor (they are always the same length and are not salted). NTLMv2 is a little better, but not  much (variable length and salted hash).

Microsoft has been strongly advising everyone to switch to Kerberos and stop using NTLM wherever possible since Windows2000 was released.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have any references for your answer? That information/links would improve your post.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ntlm-vs-kerberos/d8b139bf-6b5a-4a53-9a00-bb75d4e219eb#:~:text=NTLMv1%20hashes%20could,Multi%20Factor%20Authentication)